# Doing recursive lookup of a variable

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries to emulate a stack of environments for an interpreter. For example, in the first environment I might have the value `a=4` defined, and in the second environment I might have `b=3` defined, and so If I do `env_get(a) + env_get(b)` I should get `7`.

Here is what I currently have for this:

```
def env_get(self, k, env=None):
    v = None
    for env in reversed(self.envs): # as the "pop" is the equivalent of env[-1]
        v = env.get(k)
        if v: break
    if not v: raise AttributeError("Env does not contain '%s'" % k)
    return v
```

I was wondering if this could be condensed into a single recursive def such as the following:

```
envs=[{'a':4},{'b':3}]
def get_env_recursive(k, env_stack=None):
    if not env_stack: raise AttributeError("Env does not contain '%s'" % k)
    return env_stack[-1].get(k) or get_env_recursive(k, env_stack[:-1])
```

```
>>> get_env_recursive('a',envs)+get_env_recursive('b',envs)
7
```

Or to go crazy on a one-liner could do something like:

```
>>> getr=lambda k,env_stack: env_stack[-1].get(k) or getr(k, env_stack[:-1]) if len(env_stack)>1 else env_stack[0][k]
>>> getr('a',envs)+getr('b',envs)
# 7
```

Is there a better way I could do the above pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ChainMap` class from the `collections` module is designed for this purpose ([docs link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap)). If `env_stack` is an instance of `ChainMap` then you can simply write `env_stack[k]` to get the value for the key `k` from whichever dictionary nearest the top of the stack has that key.

For example, you can create a stack of two dictionaries like `ChainMap({'a': 4}, {'b': 3})`, where the first one is on the top of the stack. More usage examples can be found in the documentation.

Comment: oh that's really neat. Could you just show a basic example as it applies to the above?

Comment: You could just write `return self.env_stack[k]` and that's the whole function.

Comment: sure, I just mean how to set it up with a stack (or whatever the equivalent ChainMap concept is) of size two.

Comment: `ChainMap({'a': 4}, {'b': 3})` is an example; you can find more examples of how to use it in the docs. Note that the first dictionary is the top of the stack, rather than the bottom.

Comment: oh that's great! Want to just add that to the answer and I'll accept it? Is ChainMap used for a lot of 'stack-like' things? Or is basically its only usage a recursive dict lookup?

Comment: I've edited the answer to add a paragraph with that example. The first main use case is when you have configuration settings which can be set in multiple places, so you want to look up a setting e.g. in the command-line arguments, otherwise in a local config file, otherwise in a global config file. The other main use case is to model a stack of lexical scopes in a programming language, where a variable in one scope can shadow a variable of the same name in an outer scope.

Answer (score -1):

The pattern seems fine, though I'd recommend removing the default value for env_stack, as it will always cause an exception. It doesn't really make sense to have a default argument which is always invalid, so unless there's a reason to keep it, I'd remove it.

Good work!

Comment: `env_stack[-1][k]` that's wrong. It means your program would `KerError` the first time it looked it up and would never recurse. Have you tried what you suggested?

Comment: thank you for the correction @carl.hiass. I had not, no, I personally dislike using or statements in this way, so using .get() never makes a difference for me. this does give a problem when the value of the variable is falsy, so i'd recommend switching to a different way of handling that if that could ever come up